# Detour functions for third party software

Tags: hook, solaris, detours

I am interested in having a multiplatform solution to hook/detour functions (internal and external symbols) for third party software on a multiplatform environment (Windows, Linux, AIX, Solaris and HPUX).

I already have the solution implemented for windows with MS detours library, and I implemented an incomplete solution for Linux (elf executable format on x64_86 architecture) and AIX (XCOFF executable format on powerpc64 architecture).

Does anyone know of a library/guide/tutorial/another solution that implement the above for one of the following platforms?

```
Linux
AIX
Solaris (most important)
HPUX
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide an example of exactly what you're trying to do?  You probably should search for "interpose functions", too.

Comment: Hi andrew, I think you understand what I want. As I see in the net, "interpose functions" always works for functions from another shared object. I need to to do the same thing for internal functions in the executable.

It is pretty messy because I can be influenced by the compiler optimizations and stuff. but I do know that there is a MS library for this on windows. BTW, I ok if the solution will only work for unoptimized code.

Comment: What my software is destined to do, is monitor traffic coming through some function in a closed source software.